# Connecting to a machine which is only reachable through a computer which is only reachable through a VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop

I have the following problem:

I would like to connect to some machines (get their files in the Windows Explorer) without having to use a RDP connection to the controller Server, because the amount of concurent users is limited and I am always getting kicked off, because other people need to work on that machine.
 I can only connect to this controller Server using a VPN connection, so the network structure looks like this:

- My work computer can connect to the Controller Server using a VPN.
- The Controller Server can directly connect to the slave machines using their hostname.
- My work computer can *not* connect to the slave machines at all.

So, my question is, is there any way or program to get a direct connections to the slave machines without connecting to RDP on the Controller Server first? Like forwarding or something?

Comment: Are you able to make configuration changes to the firewall in front of the server? (i.e. between your client connection and the network running both the server and target machines)

Comment: No, I am not able to make such changes.

Comment: What operating system is the Controller Server running? Do you have (or can you ask someone that does have) admin privileges on the Controller Server to make changes to its configuration?

Comment: It's running Windows Server 2008. I can ask for Admin access, yes.